# WebStorm: cannot find name 'await' on certain .ts files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm

I am encountering a weird issue with WebStorm on certain files.  I am receiving "TS2304: Cannot find name 'await'" and "TS1005: ',' expected".  This is only occurring on two of several files using await/async syntax.

I have tried to invalidate cache but this did not work.  I also tried to reboot the application and the computer.  Nothing has worked so far.  Also, it seems to not have a problem with async just not await.

Here is a sample of one of the method declarations that I am getting this error from :

```
private async findUserByEmailAddress = (emailAddress): Promise<IGroupMemberModel> => {

    const user: IUserModel = await this.userRepository.findUserByEmailAddress(emailAddress);

    if (! user)
        Promise.reject(new NotFoundError("The specified user could not be found."))

    return user;
}
```

What might be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an IDE issue, it's a syntax issue. The `async` keyword should be placed before the parameter list of the arrow function:

```
private findUserByEmailAddress = async (emailAddress): Promise<IGroupMemberModel> => { 
    ... 
}
```

**Edit**

This is the full working sample based on the code, with added missing types:

```
interface IGroupMemberModel { }
interface IUserModel { }
class NotFoundError extends Error { }
class x {
    userRepository: {
        findUserByEmailAddress(emailAddress: any): Promise<IUserModel>;
    }
    private findUserByEmailAddress = async (emailAddress): Promise<IGroupMemberModel> => {

        const user: IUserModel = await this.userRepository.findUserByEmailAddress(emailAddress);

        if (!user)
            throw new NotFoundError("The specified user could not be found.");

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: That did clear up the await issue, but now I am getting "Expecting newline or semicolon", between the await and "this.".

Comment: @user1790300 It should work, you may have other syntax errors, I added the full code I tested with

Comment: Also, am I correct in returning the Promise.reject as opposed to throwing exceptions?  It seems like that flow is better.

Comment: @user1790300 No, that does not have the effect you think, you are not actually returning it. You create a Promise in the rejected state and you do nothing with it. You should throw the error. I missed that since it was not a syntactic error and I was not looking for logic errors